# Does Google cache stylesheets?

Tags: google, css, cache

Hey guys, we all know that Google caches the HTML of pages, but does it cache the corresponding CSS as well? I ask because a site I used to have and have since closed down is still in the cache and there's a CSS setup I had on it that I need to replicate on another site now. I can view the cached HTML but that doesn't help me because I don't remember what I did with the CSS.

So, does Google cache the CSS and if so, how do I view it? For those who will ask why I don't just look at my source code for the other site, I don't currently have it on my laptop and I'm not quite sure where the archive is at the moment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Viewing the source to a site that Google has cached, there is no indication that the CSS, JS, or any images are cached. I tested this by turning off one of my sites, and then looking at the cached version in Google -- it showed just the HTML, without any stylesheets, JavaScript, images, or other externally linked files.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer to your question, but if Google doesn't, the [wayback machine might](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php).

Comment: +1 - I tried WBM, but it had no cache, so I'm sad to say that's a dead end for me. On a side note, I don't even know how to get on WBM, is it automatic?

Comment: @Alex - yeah it's automatic, they index in the same way a search engine does. It can take revisions up to 12 months to end up on there if you're not a popular site, so if you try in a few months you might get lucky.